# SQL Server : syntax error converting the varchar value 'K' to a column of data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, int, varchar

We have a stored procedure that will query a table and insert 3 columns from that table into a different table. The 3 columns are a `varchar`, an `int`, and another `varchar`. When running the stored procedure, I get the error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure select_hcfa1500_EMDEONBCBS_to_build, Line 30
>   Syntax error converting the varchar value 'K' to a column of data type int.

Code:

```
declare @prov_acct_no varchar(10)
declare @icd_indicator int

select top 1 
    @prov_acct_no = left(prov_acct_no, 6), 
    @icd_indicator = icd_indicator 
from 
    hcfa1500_view_837
where 
    (map_names_element)  = 'EMDEONBCBS' 
order by 
    claim_no

INSERT INTO hcfa1500_pointer_to_build
    SELECT     
        prov_acct_no, claim_no, map_names_element
    FROM         
        hcfa1500_view_837
    WHERE     
        (map_names_element = 'EMDEONBCBS') 
        AND left(prov_acct_no, 6) = @prov_acct_no 
        AND icd_indicator = @icd_indicator
```

This code has the error on line 30 which is the `insert into` statement.

I'm just at a bit of a loss as each column is being inserted into it's same variable, `varchar` to `varchar` and `int` to `int`. Even looking through all the data, I don't see any 'K' in any row or column, which just causes more confusion.  We have tried restarting the server with the database, but no luck. Does anyone know why the stored procedure would find something like this in a column that isn't actually there?

Comment: What is the value being returned for `icd_indicator` by the view?

Comment: Is hcfa1550_view_837 actually a table or a view as its name suggests? Can you do a `select distinct icd_indicator from hcfa1500_view_837`?

Comment: Also is there only three columns in `hcfa1500_pointer_to_build` ??? try explicitly mentioning the column names in the insert statement.

Comment: The value returned by the view I believe is a `varchar`, though I'm not extremely familiar with this view as it was set up years ago. The `hcfa1500_view_837` is a view, I ran the the query you suggested and returned a blank, a K, 0, and 9 which would lead me to believe this is where the problem would lie, though I don't recall the ICD indicator ever being an int. Yes, there is only 3 columns in the 'hcfa1500_pointer_to_build'.

Comment: I see now the `icd_indicator` was declared `int` in the procedure, so I believe that removing this entry with the K should solve the problem.